# Why does my IFNA (or ISNA) not working in a VBA module?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

i have the following code:

```
Sub TestNA2()
IsThisNA = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D:D").Select
'Sheets("sheet1").Range("E:E").Select
Range("E2").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(D1),""Delete"","""")"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E:E"), Type:=xlFillDefault
'ActiveCell.Value = "=IF(ISNA(D:D), ""Delete"","""")"
'ActiveCell.Value = IsThisNA
'MsgBox IsNA
End Sub
```

but it errors out on this line: ActiveCell.Value = IfNa(D6, "Delete")

what i want to happen is to put the word "delete" in cell E6 if D6 is #NA.

can someone help me out with this code?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this row:

```
ActiveCell.Value = IfNa(D6, "Delete")
```

Use instead:

```
Set IsThisNA = Sheets("items-1").Range("D6")
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(IsThisNA.Value) Then 
  ActiveCell.Value = "Delete"
End If
```

or, more succinctly:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Sheets("items-1").Range("D6").Value) Then 
  ActiveCell.Value = "Delete"
End If
```

Comment: i tried what you wrote but getting this error on the IF statement: run time error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: Have you tried If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(IsThisNA.Value) Then  ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a string out of the formula. You have:

```
ActiveCell.Value = IfNa(D6, "Delete")
```

But this should be:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNA(D6), ""Delete"","""")"
```

Note that I added the second parameter of `IF` to be the empty string, but you might want to change this.

Note: you can use [`IFNA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461) since Excel 2011 instead of `IF(ISNA(..),..)`.

**Edit:** based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031794/1771479) you can extend it for the whole column:

```
Range("E1").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(D1),""Delete"","""")"
Range("E1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E:E"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You can also put a fixed range, for example `E1:E6`, as indicated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031794/1771479).

**Edit 2:** if you want to fill it for the whole column, you should put the formula on row 1 (e.g. `E1`), and do the auto fill over the whole column (e.g. `E:E`). If you want less rows you should indicate that in the auto fill destination, for example:

```
Range("E2").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(D6),""Delete"","""")"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

So the auto fill range is starting at the same location as the formula (`E2` in this example).

Comment: how can i make this work on a column, like so: (not working)
    `code`Sub TestNA()
    IsThisNA = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D:D").Select
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("E:E").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "=IF(ISNA(D:D), ""Delete"","""")"
    'ActiveCell.Value = IsThisNA
    'MsgBox IsNA
    End Sub`code`

Comment: so it fails on the last range: Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E:E"), Type:=xlFillDefault, see original post for new code block